# JSON python error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

while running script sometimes error come up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dzwon\Desktop\osu_pp_watch_v15_FINAL.py", line 27, in <module>
    data=(requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=' + APIkey + '&u=' + username)).json()
  File "C:\Users\dzwon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 894, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dzwon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\dzwon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\dzwon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Error can popup after 15 or 2 minutes or won't popup at all

the part of script that parse JSON

```
 data=(requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=' + APIkey + '&u=' + username)).json()
 pp = data[0]['pp_raw']
 rank = data[0]['pp_rank']
```

and the JSON data

```
[{"user_id":"5390233","username":"dzwon21","count300":"439843","count100":"39207","count50":"5245","playcount":"3860","ranked_score":"753280488","total_score":"1708595594","pp_rank":"223986","level":"63.7695","pp_raw":"842.426","accuracy":"97.04467010498047","count_rank_ss":"53","count_rank_s":"235","count_rank_a":"264","country":"PL","pp_country_rank":"10947","events":[{"display_html":"<b><a href='\/u\/5390233'>dzwon21<\/a><\/b> unlocked the \"<b>Insanity Approaches<\/b>\" medal!","beatmap_id":"0","beatmapset_id":"0","date":"2017-07-12 17:43:17","epicfactor":"4"}]}]
```

Comment: It's probably that your request returns something else than valid JSON from time to time. Try to log the content you receive from the server before trying to decode it, or when an error occurs.

Comment: I will try and post if something wrong will come out

Answer (score 2):

Your HTTP request is failing. You should check the success or failure of your HTTP request before grabbing the JSON data:

```
 #UNTESTED
 result=requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=' + APIkey + '&u=' + username)
 if result.ok and  result.headers['content-type'] ==  'application/json':
     data = result.json()
 else:
     raise SomeError("HTTP did not return data.")

 pp = data[0]['pp_raw']
 rank = data[0]['pp_rank']
```

Comment: So,I edited a little bit code and put it in and code is not detecting http request failing. new error https://pastebin.com/nC2US6yF